# Please check my solution.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

A group of order 48 must have a normal subgroup of order 8 or 16 .
Solution:Let G be a group of order n.
Let H be a normal subgroup of G.
Then G/H is a group.
Then by Lagrange's Theorem o(G/H)=o(G)/o(H)
So in this case order of G is 48 and divisors of 48 are 8 and 16.
so  a group of order 48 must have a normal subgroup of order 8 or 16 .
Is may way correct?

Comment: No, Lagrange's Theorem doesn't state that there exists normal subgroups of certain orders. It just tells you that the only possible orders of subgroups are the divisors of the order of the group.

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem is applicable to a group with finite order.So can't I use that theorem to solve this question?

Comment: You can apply it, but it still doesn't tell you about the existence of any subgroups.

Comment: One way of proving the existence of subgroups of certain orders is provided by Sylow's Theorems, which provide a partial converse to Lagrange. Once a subgroup is shown to exist it may be a further step to show that it is normal.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is incorrect. For example, the group $A_5$ of order $60$ has no non-trivial normal subgroups, but I could use your argument to show that it must have a normal subgroup of order $2$ or $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Lagrange's theorem states if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$. The converse is not true at all.

Have you learned about the Sylow theorems?

Comment: No.It seems this question is out of syllabus because it uses concept of Sylow theorems which is not in my syllabus.

Comment: Is this a qualifier/prelim level syllabus, or an undergrad syllabus?  If your syllabus mentions "classification of groups of small/medium order," then the Sylow Theorems are really implied.  Either way, they are pretty fundamental to group theory and well worth studying.

Comment: undergraduate level syllabus.

Comment: Unless it has a very unorthodox program, any decent Mathematics Dept.'s group theory's undergraduate syllabus includes Sylow Theorems, which are elementary and rather important.